SwiftUI TextField gap while animating the keyboard
I'm creating a chat-style interface with SwiftUI with a TextField at the bottom and a List of items above it. When the text field receives focus and the keyboard comes up, the field and its background don't stay attached to the keyboard but rather move a little ahead or behind it. Here's an example:

This was done using a safeAreaInset:
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var message = ""
  
  var body: some View {
    List([Color.red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .blue, .indigo, .purple], id: \.self) { color in
      color
        .frame(height: 150)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    }
    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
      TextField("Chat", text: $message)
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .padding()
        .background(.thinMaterial)
    }
  }
}

I get similar results arranging them in a VStack:
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      List([Color.red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .blue, .indigo, .purple], id: \.self) { color in
        color
          .frame(height: 150)
          .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
      }
      .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)

      TextField("Chat", text: $message)
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        .padding()
        .background(.thinMaterial)
    }
  }

The animation timing wouldn't be too big a problem if the background behind the text field extended to the keyboard while animating. Tried doing this with ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom) but this had no apparent effect.
I found that Casey Liss's excellent Callsheet has found a way to do it (he's mentioned that he used SwiftUI for the app), but I'm not sure how. Here's what Callsheet looks like as the keyboard comes in:

Anyone know how to accomplish this behavior?

I can't actually reproduce this on iOS 17.4 (or perhaps my eyes are just bad at seeing fast moving things). What iOS version are you using?

The demos used Xcode 15.4 and iOS 17.5. I get the same result using Xcode 16 beta 6 with iOS 18. The behavior is inconsistent but persistent. The keyboard moves pretty fast so it's only momentary (but very annoying). Turn on slow animations to see it more easily.

Are you sure it's not the .scrollContentBackground(.hidden) that causes the actual gap? Also, have you confirmed this also happens on real devices. Simulators sometimes...

The scrollContentBackground modifier is just there to cover a different UI bug -- the behavior I described still happens if you remove it. And yes, you get the same thing on a device (using iOS 17.5 on the phone -- don't have an iOS 18 device handy but it's pretty unlikely that would be the difference).

Those of you closing as typo: why? Using a ShapeStyle in place of a View requiring a ViewModifier is not a typo!

Making the TextField exactly match the animation of the keyboard is futile as one may use third-party keyboards or other such keyboard replacements that have their own presenting animation.
Instead, you're right to want the background to be presented after the TextField. You mention you tried doing this with ignoresSafeArea without effect, but don't say exactly where you tried it in the code, leading me to believe it was simply attached to the wrong view.
The view you want ignoring the safe area of the keyboard is specifically the background. In your case, that's a thin material. Therefore the material needs the safe area ignoring.
thinMaterial is a ShapeStyle, not a View, so ViewModifiers cannot be applied directly.
Instead, create the view yourself and apply the modifier.
struct ContentView: View {
    …
    var body: some View {
        …
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            TextField("Chat", text: $message)
                …
                .background {
                    Rectangle().fill(.thinMaterial).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }
        }
    }
}

When the bottom safe area is extended up by the keyboard, the background behind is the thin material.


As you say, I was attaching the safe area extension to the wrong view. Greatly appreciated the help. One minor adjustment though -- instead of edgesIgnoringSafeArea which is deprecated, I'd recommend ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
